# Pandas datetime indexing in plots

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I've been having problems with different types of formatting on my xAxis in my plots.
When I load my data from a .csv file with the errorhandling "forward fill" (df.ffill()) I get the following plot:

[image: Plot for forward fill]

Which is extremely neat! However, when I errorhandle with df.drop() I get this plot:

[image: Plot for drop]

Which does not have the same type of formatting on the xAxis as the first plot, which is both annoying and not as pretty / useful as the first plot.

I'm thinking it has to do with the amount of data? But honestly I have no idea. I've been googling for hours and found no particular answer on how to specify the first type of formatting as a plotting parameter.

My code is as follows:

```
# Create a date-type series
# tvec is an Nx6 matrix where each column represents [year,month,day,hour,min,sec]
# pltData is an Nx4 matrix where each column is a positive float value

xAxis = pd.to_datetime(tvec)  
xLabel = "Date"  # Set label

# Set xAxis as index to data
pltData = pltData.set_index([xAxis]) 

# Plot data with use of pandas plotting function
pltData.plot(ax=ax,
             title="Consumption per {}".format(period))

# Add options to plot and draw to canvas
plt.xlabel(xLabel)  # Add x-label
plt.ylabel(self.unit)  # Add y-label
# Define plot parameters
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9, bottom=0.255, left=0.1, right=0.955,
                        hspace=0.2, wspace=0.2)  # adjust size
canvas.draw()  # Draw to canvas
```

I am using a FigureCanvas to plot on in a GUI created in PyQt5

Comment: I have the impression that currently the only reliable way of obtaining reproducible datetime formatting on axes is not to use pandas, but plot with matplotlib directly and use the various `matplotlib.dates` locators and formatters.

Comment: In my case, how am I to use the matplotlib.dates to get the same type of formatting as the first picture?

Comment: Where is the problem? If you provide a [mcve], I can also help you. Is having the year shown only for January required or may it be on all ticks?